# Why is the assumption $E(\epsilon|X)$ called the "exogeneity assumption"?

Tags: regression, econometrics, exogeneity

In regression analysis, my book says that the condition $E(\epsilon_i|X_i)$ is called the "exogeneity assumption" and that the condition $E(\epsilon_i|X_1, ..., X_n)$ is called the "strict exogeneity assumption".

**Why are they called this way? What do they have to do with the conceptual idea of $X$ being exogeneous, i.e. not influenced by variables inside the regression model?**

Comment: Have you seen this terminology in the context of systems of equations (like supply and demand) and are struggling to understand the connection to the econometric usage? Or are you confused by what makes the second notion stricter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon|X_i)$ is called the exogenity assumption is because we don't what the error term to be correlated with our indepenent $X$ terms.

Recall that in your basic linear regression model, you assume a dependent and a (or a few) independent variables.

when you have $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon|X_i)\ne0$ you implicitly have $X$ as a function of $\epsilon $ i.e $X=f(\epsilon)$. This is the issue of **Endogenity**.

If you have endogenity the coeffienct estimates that you will get will be baised  and not actually represent their true effect on your dependent variable because they are based on the the value residuals $\epsilon_i$.